# Default value along with uniqueness validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Path model with `name` attribute as unique. I want to set default value as `'/'`
 to the same.
I have done in the following manner.

```
class Path < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  before_validation :set_default_path

  private

  def set_default_path
    self.name = name.presence || '/'
  end
end
```

Domain model is designed as:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, path_id

  validates :name, :path_id, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: {scope: :path_id}
end
```

But this doesn't work for consecutive inserts with a blank name for path.

```
path = Path.find_or_create_by_name('')

domain = Domain.new(name: 'stackoverflow.com')
domain.path = path
domain.save!  # Fails with validation error
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Path can't be blank
```

Is there a robust way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove following callback

```
before_validation :set_default_path
```

and use validation for name as following:--

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, :if => 'name.present?'
```

and write a migration file to add default value to name attribute of paths table as either of followings:--

```
change_column :paths, :name, :string, :default => '/'
```

or

```
change_column_default :paths, :name, '/'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The validation is not failing for path but for domain. Also I could have done `allow_blank: true`. The quest is how's it possible for `find_or_create` initialize with default if its blank. This way if would find the existing default path('/'). I have provided my Domain class see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

add condition on validation:

```
validates :name, presence: true
validates :name, uniqueness: true, unless: proc { |e| e.name == "/" }
```